# How to pass parameters to all API controller constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

MVC Web:  We can pass the parameter to all controller constructor by implementing DefaultControllerFactory to my own Base controller to pass the parameter to all controller constructor.

Similar way i want to do it for API controller also.

Example MVC Web Controller

```
 public class BaseController : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    readonly IRepository _readOnlyRepository;

    public BaseController()
    {
        _readOnlyRepository = _readOnlyRepository ?? new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerType = GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
        return (IController)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[]
        {
            _readOnlyRepository
        }, null);
    }
}
```

How can i pass the parameter to all API Controllers